# Wordpress page templates in a directory

Tags: theme-development, page-template, directory

I'm trying to organize my `page-$slug.php` files all inside a folder, i saw in a post that it was possible to store the files inside a directory in the root path of the theme...
i tried to store them like this

[image]

But the `page-termos-e-condicoes.php` wasn't recognized.. is there any other way to do it?

Comment: you cannot store specialized page templates in a sub-folder; https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#creating-a-custom-page-template-for-one-specific-page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file needs a [template header](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#creating-custom-page-templates-for-global-use) and will only behave as a user-selectable custom page template.

True special templates like `page-$slug.php` that match the post's slug will only work when they live in the root theme directory.